# Bind AngleProperty of the image in code

Tags: c#, wpf

**UPDATE**

I want to add an image to my canvas programmatically. I want to bind X, Y coords and Angle of the Image. X and Y binding works fine, but the Angle doesn't. Here is the code:

```
    public void AddNewImage()
    {
        Image newImage = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath))
        };
```

**These two work fine**

```
        Binding binding1 = new Binding("X");
        binding1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding1.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(newImage, Canvas.LeftProperty, binding1);

        Binding binding2 = new Binding("Y");
        binding2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding2.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(newImage, Canvas.TopProperty, binding2);
```

**That's why I use a group**

```
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(xTranslate,yTranslate));
        tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform());
        newImage.RenderTransform = tg;
```

**This one doesn't work**

```
        Binding binding3 = new Binding("Angle");
        binding3.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding3.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(tg, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, binding3);

        MainCanvas.Children.Add(newImage);          
    }
```

When I change X and Y - image moves, but when I change angle - nothing happens.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Use an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the binding on the TransformGroup, which has no `Angle` property. Instead of that you should set the binding directly on the RotateTransform.

```
var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();

var tg = new TransformGroup();
tg.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
newImage.RenderTransform = tg;

var binding3 = new Binding("Angle");
...
BindingOperations.SetBinding(rotateTransform, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, binding3);
```

Comment: But what if I need to have not only RotateTransform?